# Social login concept and best practice

Tags: oauth-2.0, laravel-6, google-signin, user-management

I have started building a website on Laravel and I wanted to include social Login to my site.

I have a basic understanding of how this works. I used Socialite and Google API and followed the documentation and setup a login route to google and was able to get a response with token and other details.

This is where I am stuck. I wan't to build a robust user system. I need help in understanding the best concept for Social login.

For example,
when a user logs in from google, do I need to save the token. Do I need to create an entry in the database and save as a user or should I just load the user information every time from what is returned by the API.

Also, what is the difference between social login and sing up with social login?

Ultimately, I would like to build a site with user profiles and I would like to get as much information from API's as possible and setup the user system in efficient way.

Any help is much appreciated